# How to upload to a specific YouTube channel with Oauth2 and YouTube API v3

Tags: api, oauth, upload, youtube

I'm following YouTube's API V3 guide to uploading a video using Oauth2:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

However, it's not clear to me how to upload to a specific user's channel. The guide allows for a place to specify client id, client secret id, and I have both.

I also have both an access and refresh token to that authorizes uploads to a specific channel, but I don't see where I include my access token.

Please shed some light ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same thing earlier this month, and the answer I found is that you don't need to add the channel in your request.
Indeed, when you ask OAuth2 credentials, you are prompted to select a channel, and this channel is linked to the credentials you obtain. Therefore when you upload your video, the channel will be determined by the access token you are using.

Therefore, if you wanted to use a different channel, you would need to get credentials for that other channel, but there is no option to specify it as parameter. If ever you need to switch between channels, this [article](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api_24.html) is very interesting.

I hope this will *light* your way ;-)

Comment: Channels are not showing up unfortunately. I am logged in with an email that is a manager but the channel does not show up as an option.

Answer (score -1):

The [YouTube API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) lists two ways that you can send the Access Token:

> The API supports the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol. You can
>   provide an OAuth 2.0 token in either of the following ways:
>
> - Use the access_token query parameter like this:    ?access_token=oauth2-token
> - Use the HTTP Authorization header like this: Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token
>
> Complete instructions for implementing OAuth 2.0 authentication in
>   your application can be found in the the [authentication guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).